# npm ERR! Cannot find module 'through2'

Tags: node.js, node-modules

Whenever i do anything node relates whether it be npm install, starting a .js script or even installing modules i get this error:

> 'npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND 
>         npm ERR! Cannot find module 'through2'

- i tried deleting node and reinstalling but still get it.
- it randomly happened to, it seemed like out of the blue. any help would be great as this is a constant problem in my work.

Comment: Can you mention the version of node & npm you are using

Comment: can you  delete npm in you user/local/lib/node_modules/npm and install npm again

Answer (score 0):

If you delete your node_modules folder and try npm i it should work.
Also, if you are using gulp I think you can find your answer here [cannot find module through2 while installing gulp](http://You%20should%20first%20make%20sure%20that%20through2%20is%20in%20your%20package.json.%20If%20it%20isn't,%20run%20npm%20--save-dev%20through2.%20%20If%20it%20is%20in%20your%20package.json%20run%20npm%20install%20to%20make%20sure%20its%20pulled%20in.%20%20If%20it%20is%20installed,%20check%20your%20gulpfile.js%20has%20require('through2')%20in%20it.)

Answer (score 0):

whatever module is missing, try using

```
npm install <module-name>@latest
```

even if this doesn't work there is another manage packager as npm known as yarn.

Try using it. Then by yarn it will be

```
yarn add <module-name>
```

it worked for me hope it works for you.